# Symfony2 - Stateful API key authentication without session cookie

Tags: php, api, symfony, session

I followed this article on API key authentication with Symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

It explains the authentication part well, but it doesn't seem to explain how state between requests works outside of a normal session.

> But in some situations (like an OAuth flow), the token may be sent on
>   only one request. In this case, you will want to authenticate the user
>   and store that authentication in the session so that the user is
>   automatically logged in for every subsequent request.

That makes sense but *how* is the user linked back to the session on subsequent requests, if a token is only provided on the first? I can't use a session cookie because CORS restrictions won't allow me to.

What I'm basically trying to achieve is an API that I can POST login credentials to, in return for an access token that allows me to link requests back to a session.

Can anybody help fill in some of the blanks, or suggest a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

> That makes sense but how is the user linked back to the session on subsequent requests, if a token is only provided on the first?

If you use the native session handler, your session and session id as well as a session cookie is sent to the client automatically by PHP's session handler, as soon as you request the session in Symfony.

> I can't use a session cookie because CORS restrictions won't allow me to.

Then you can't use a authentication mechanism that provides only at the very beginning (first request) a security key, without sending any other api key in subsequent requests.

> What I'm basically trying to achieve is an API that I can POST login credentials to, in return for an access token that allows me to link requests back to a session.

Then do exactly what the linked documentation is doing. Provide additionally a route (not protected) for everyone that accepts credentials and returns a api key. That api key is then used in all subsequent requests, as described in the linked documentation.